# How to customize Vertical position of self.title in IOS 4.0?

Tags: iphone, xcode

How can I set/customize setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment in iOS 4.0? I need suggestion.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor]; 
    label.font = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"XXII DIRTY-ARMY" size: 32.0 ];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0f];

    label.text=NSLocalizedString(@"HomeTitle", @"Home");
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor   newBrownLight];
    label.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 44);

    self.navigationItem.titleView = label; 
    self.navigationItem.title=label.text;
```

}

Comment: http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779190/using-uiappearance-to-change-label-height